# JAVA авторизация на сайте через post запрос, при отправке второго get запроса сайт просит авторизоваться

Tags: java

я подключился к сайту через HttpURLConnection и отправил post запрос(для авторизации). После того как авторизация прошла успешно мне нужно отправить другой get запрос.
Все работает хорошо как часы,но проблема в том что когда я отправляю get запрос сайт просит авторизоваться снова. Помогите плиз) заранее спасибо!

Вод код:

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://сайт.com/account").openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    String params = "qs=&user=Логин&pss=Пароль";
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    byte[] data = params.getBytes("UTF-8");
    os.write(data);
    data = null;
    params = "user=Логин&v2=1&v3=1&v4=1&v5=1&forcelogout=1";
   conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://сайт.com/autosurf").openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
    data = params.getBytes("UTF-8");
    os.write(data);
    data = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));  
    while(true){
    while(br.ready()){
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
}}
```

Comment: данные сессии, куки нужно подсовывать при каждом обращении к сайту. Проблема только в этом. Вы не отправляете какой-то параметр, по которому сайт считает, что вы авторизованы.

Comment: Сессия обычно поддреживается с помощью куков. А Вы каждый раз делаете вот это `CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());` Новый менеджер куков не принимает куки от предшественника. Соответственно следующим запросом не возможно подтвердить продолжение сессии.

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Как сделать по другому ?

Comment: @ArchDemon Спасибо за быстрый ответ! как его отправить ?

Comment: Может его вообще не трогать, оставить системный. Или установить только раз в начале сессии.

Comment: @Sergey как это ? И что где написать?

Comment: Где начинается сессия с сервером там и написать. Перед тем как посылать любые запросы. Можно в самом начале программы.

Comment: @Sergey вы об этом ? 'CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());'

Comment: Ну да. 12345678

Comment: @Sergey так он же у меня стоит, я потом к другому сайт подключаюсь. Сначала к                                            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://сайт.com/account").openConnection();
     затем                                                                                                                      conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://сайт.com/autosurf").openConnection();

Comment: Не пытались установку куки-менеджера делать до `первого openConnection`, а не `между двумя openConnection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в первом запросе мы получаем cookie с сайта и сохраняем их в переменю

```
cookie = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
```

затем когда делаем второй запрос достаём cookie из переменой и отправляем на сайт

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
```